# Laravel passing multiple parameter to controller

Tags: laravel, controller, parameter-passing

I want to delete an image and return back to user page, so i try to pass 2 parameter to my controller (my userid and image_id).

But I get this error

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\McuFormDocumentController::destroy(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

My button code in blade

```
<button id="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-title="{{ $mcu_form_document['title'] }}"
        style="color: #fff; font-size: 1.2em;"
        href="{{ route('mcu-form-document.destroy', ['id'=>$id ,'img'=>$mcu_form_document['id']]) }}">
    Delete <i class="la la-trash" style="color: #fff; font-size: 1.2em;"></i>
</button>

<form action="{{ route('mcu-form-document.destroy', ['id'=>$id ,'img'=>$mcu_form_document['id']]) }}" method="post" id="deleteForm">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}

    <input type="submit" value="" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

My controller

```
public function destroy($id,$img_id)
{
    $mcu_form_document = McuFormDocument::find($img_id);
    $mcu_form_document->delete();

    return redirect()
        ->route('mcu.resume.list', ['id' => $id])
        ->with('success', 'Document has been successfully deleted!');
}
```

my route

```
    Route::resource('mcu-resume', 'McuResumeController');
```

Comment: check your routes `php artisan route:list` that resource isn't going to make any route with more than 1 parameter

Comment: yes, can you show me more what to do?

Comment: you will have to define a route yourself that takes 2 parameters ... but why do you need your 'user_id' passed?

Comment: i need user_id to route back to that user edit page

Comment: you would either need to create this as a nested resource or create your own delete route that takes 2 parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution is using concatenation when passing the params in href

```
 href="{{ route('mcu-form-document.destroy', $id .'|'.$mcu_form_document['id']) }}"
```

and split it with preg_split in my controller

```
    public function destroy($params)
    {
    $str_arr = preg_split("/\|/", $params);
    $id = $str_arr[0];
    $img_id = $str_arr[1];
    // dd($id . "-" . $img_id);
    }
```

hope this will help others..thx for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also add a request parameter into your controller which enables you to pass multiple data and get the required value as below:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function destroy(Request $request)
{
   $id = $request->get('id');
   $image_id = $request->get('img');
   $mcu_form_document = McuFormDocument::find($image_id);
   $mcu_form_document->delete();

   return redirect()
    ->route('mcu.resume.list', ['id' => $id])
    ->with('success', 'Document has been successfully deleted!');
 }


 //web.php
 Route::delete('mcu-resume-destroy', 'McuResumeController@destroy');
```

Comment: got null for $id

Comment: can you try using 

    action('McuFormDocumentController@destroy', [ 
             'id' => $id, 
              'img'=>$mcu_form_document['id']
    ])


should have worked with route() too.